# Is it nessesary to use getStaticProps with json import in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to render static data that is coming from a JSON or typescript file and display it to the user. Do I have to use `getStaticProps` or can I simply import the data without `getStaticProps`? It's not clear to me after reading the next documentation.

**projects.tsx**

```
const projects: [
  {
    id: "6853939";
    name: "Project 01";
    title: "Title 01 ";
    previewImg: "/images/projectThumbnails/image01.jpg";
  },
  {
    id: "6853939";
    name: "Project 02";
    title: "Title 02 ";
    previewImg: "/images/projectThumbnails/image02.jpg";
  }
];

export default projects;
```

**names.json**

```
{
  "names": [
    { "name": "Full Name 01", "age": 34 },
    { "name": "Full Name 02", "age": 22 },
  ],
}
```

**index.tsx**

```
import projects from "../data/projects.tsx";
import names from "../data/names.json";

const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {projects.map((i) => (
          <div key={i.id}>{i.title}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        {names.names.map((i) => (
          <div key={i.name}>{i.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's totally up to you which approach you are going to use .

**With `getStaticProps`:**

server uses `JSON` data to inject data and create cache

**Without `getStaticProps`:**

JSON file would be injected in client side , without being cached

*I prsonally recommend using `getStaticProps`*

Comment: What do you mean by injected? Isn't a JSON file that's already in my next directory already cached? Why do you prefer `getServerSideProps` for a static page? This would only be useful for changing content when making requests to an API.

Comment: What's the difference when using JSON on the server and JSON on the client side? Aren't they both the same as they're a JSON file.

Comment: i meant `getStaticProps `, sorry for that . when you pass the json ( data ) to the server using `getStaticProps` , server creates HTML and does'nt pass the json to the client. but without `getStaticProps` your json would be downloaded inside browser and consumes more computational power than static HTML file.

Comment: Thanks! To make it complete can you write the solution with getStaticProps in your answer? I saw that some of the documentation used the file system api to load data into getStaticProps is that also necessary for JSON? [Link](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/implement-getstaticprops)

Comment: yes you can use `fs.readFileSync( path, options )` to load json. you can also import it easily.

Answer (score 1):

Importing JSON in `getStaticProps`:

```js
import yourJson from ('./somefile.json')


export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  
  //use your json here 
  
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```